# CheckBox в TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

Требуется в элемент TreeView

```
<TreeView Name="TreeViewExpenseItems">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}"
                                  DataType="treeViewItems:ExpenseItemNode">

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                           Margin="5,0,0,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Отобразить чекбоксы на каждом узле. Естественно, при изменении значения IsChecked одного из узлов должны меняться значения всех дочерних элементов, вплоть до листов. Для этого в модели, элементы который привязываются к источнику данных, это значение меняется рекурсивно:

```
public class ExpenseItemNode
{
    public ExpenseItemNode(long id, string code, string name, bool isChecked = false)
    {
        Id = id;
        Code = code;
        Name = name;
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ExpenseItemNode>();
        IsChecked = isChecked;
    }

    public long Id { get; }
    public string Code { get; }
    public string Name { get; }

    private bool _isChecked;

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get => _isChecked;
        set
        {
            _isChecked = value;

            foreach (ExpenseItemNode item in Items)
                SetChildChecks(item, value);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ExpenseItemNode> Items { get; }

    private static void SetChildChecks(ExpenseItemNode item, bool value)
    {
        item.IsChecked = value;

        foreach (ExpenseItemNode child in item.Items)
            SetChildChecks(child, value);
    }
}
```

Но есть несколько проблем:

1. Если узел развернуть и кликнуть на чекбокс, то внешний вид дочерних узлов не изменится, хотя значения меняются корректно.
2. Такой подход работает только при клике на родительские узлы. При клике на дочерние узлы состояние родительских не изменится.

Каким образом заставить TreeView работать корректно? То есть:
1. Изменять состояния дочерних узлов при клике на родительский
2. Изменять состояния родительских узлов при клике на дочерний (в том числе, оставлять закрашенный квадрат, если в родительском элементе не выбраны все дочерние).

Может быть, у кого-то есть пример того, как это правильно реализовать?

Comment: вы же используете привязки, то есть ваши вьюмодели должны реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged` и создавать событие о изменении в сеттере `IsChecked`

Comment: @tym32167 хм. Да, оказалось довольно просто. А скажите, в правильном ли я направлении двигаюсь, реализовывая изменение состояния зависящих узлов вручную? Или есть более просто способ?

Comment: если это решает вашу задачу, то почему нет